# Suppress the "Watermark value will not be updated since poll processor returned no results" message in Mule Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm newly learning Mulesoft's Anypoint Studio.  I'm experimenting with the Polling Scope and the Watermark functionality is working well in my test, but when there are no new records in my incoming Database endpoint, I get the "Watermark value will not be updated since poll processor returned no results" message logged in my console.  Is there a way to suppress this message?  I don't want to know that the Watermark was not updated.

(I wouldn't mind knowing when the Watermark was updated and what it was updated with, but that doesn't get logged in the Console, oddly enough, and that's not really the topic of this post anyway, though.  So, no big deal.  Was just thinking out loud about it.  Ha, ha!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the level inside the Log4j2.xml to avoid printing all the info messages.  Just add below line inside Log4j2.xml:

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.transport.polling.watermark.Watermark" level="WARM"/>
```

Notice that now the level is WARM and not INFO.  Not sure if this the behaviour that you want to achieve. Additionally, you can apply different filters to manage the information you want to print. Check the Log4j2 documentation for a better understanding.

Regards!

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, Mario!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to open the "src/main/resources/log4j2.xml" file, go to the "Source" view of the file, and added  `<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.transport.polling.watermark.Watermark" level="WARN"/>`  And that did exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again!